# npm errors Angular 9.0.7 Installation Issues

Tags: angular, npm

I am stuck with issue. My project was running quite well a week ago. My windows update has corrupt my windows. I reinstall my windows and after that i am unablt to run my angular project. My project was in angular 9.0.7 and i have package.json. I try by installing angular 9.0.7 globally and locally and then run npm install. it gives me following error
I try with node modules 12 and 14
Initially it looks that it is installing creating node modules folder. but after these errors node-modules folder removed.
Here was my old configuration of ng --version

[image]

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'D:\\Simplicity\\Repositories\\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@12.14.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n' +
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     '    at getNotFoundError (D:\\Simplicity\\Repositories\\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n' +
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F (D:\\Simplicity\\Repositories\\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n' +
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     '    at E (D:\\Simplicity\\Repositories\\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n' +
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     '    at D:\\Simplicity\\Repositories\\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n' +
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     '    at D:\\Simplicity\\Repositories\\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n' +
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     '    at D:\\Simplicity\\Repositories\\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n' +
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     '    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)',
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python\n' +
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     '    at getNotFoundError (D:\\Simplicity\\Repositories\\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n' +
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F (D:\\Simplicity\\Repositories\\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n' +
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     '    at E (D:\\Simplicity\\Repositories\\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n' +
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     '    at D:\\Simplicity\\Repositories\\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n' +
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     '    at D:\\Simplicity\\Repositories\\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n' +
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     '    at D:\\Simplicity\\Repositories\\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n' +
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     '    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)',
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
npm ERR! gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at callback (D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:306:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Simplicity\\Repositories\\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\Simplicity\Repositories\s4b-simplicitycloud.ownerweb-new\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v12.14.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

Comment: Install `Python2` on your system. I would advice to use latest version of `Node` and `Angular`.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps, they helps me to resolve it:

1. Install python 2.7 on your machine
2. The latest node version doesn't work. node version 14.16.1 worked for me. please install this version.
3. reopen CMD/ windows Power Shell to take effect of the new version.
4. use this parameter while running npm install --legacy-peer-deps

These steps resolved my issue.